# How to use Python format to pre-pend a specified number of spaces to a string

Tags: python, formatting

How do I use the string `format` function to pre-pend a specified number of spaces to a string? Everything I search (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835810/how-to-add-x-number-of-spaces-to-a-string)) tells me to use something like

```
"{:>15}".format("Hello")
```

But that will give me 10 spaces in front. What if I always want to put 4 spaces in front, keeping things left-aligned, when the input strings are of variable length? For example:

```
    Hello
    Goodbye
```

I thought of doing

```
"{:4}{}".format("", "Hello")
```

Which does work, but then I have to pass in this bogus empty string. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: simply adding 4 spaces in the formatted string does what you want ? `____{}".format(foo)` ( I had to put underscores as stackoverflow removes multiple spaces)

Comment: @Oniro but what if I wanted 13 spaces. I'm not going to sit there and count out 13 spaces. That is actually precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can try `f-strings`. Something like `f"{'':4}{'Hello'}"`

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, `"{}{}".format(" "*n, foo)` will give you `n` spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use format, but [`textwrap.indent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent) does what you want.

```
 >>> import textwrap
 >>> s = 'hello\n\n \nworld'
 >>> textwrap.indent(s, ' ' * 4)
 '    hello\n\n \n  world'
```

Python also allows you to define your own [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864302/add-custom-conversion-types-for-string-formatting/19864463#19864463) an example of how to override it. In this case, it might look like:

```
import string
import re

class Template(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        if re.match('\d+t', spec):
            value = ' ' * int(spec[:-1]) + value
            spec = ''
        return super(Template, self).format_field(value, spec)
```

Usage:

```
>>> fmt = Template().format
>>> fmt('{:4t} {}', 'hello', 'world')
    hello world
```

Studying the format string language, I do not see a way to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have n as your number of spaces required

```
newString = f'{" "*n}oldstring'
```

should add n spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function and define the number of spaces or type of indent you want:

```
def indent(word, n = 1, style = ' '):
    print(f"{style * n}->{word}")

indent('hello', n = 10)
>>          ->hello

indent('hello', n = 10, style = '*')
>>**********->hello
```

You can change the default value of the `n` keyword or `style` according to your needs so that you won't have to always have to use `f-strings` or `format` on every output.